# Delayed job Failing with noe reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, ruby-2.0

I am running a quite simple rails app, that sends emails with ActionMailer whenever a user completes a form.

The problem I have is that DelayedJob is failing without any errors.

I run delayed job by typing:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job stop
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

and start running fine.

The problem comes when sometimes I get this message instead of the usual one:

```
pid-file for killed process 14653 found (/home/rails/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid), deleting.
```

Why is it killed? After that is gone, DJ start shooting off dozens of emails that were 'stuck'.

How can I avoid this? Is it a server issue (maximum running process timeout?)

Thanks

Comment: My logs dont show any errors, just INFO messages

Comment: looks like your job-worker dies at some point. this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330544/delayed-job-stops-running-after-some-time-in-production